# Git won't add certain globs

Tags: git, bash

I'm left scratching my head on this one. So, in git on OSX, you can add files like:

```
git add *.java
```

and it will add all files that have the *.java extension. Same for .txt, json, etc. However, when I do a

```
git add *.xml
```

nothing happens. It's not specified in my gitignore, so git is reporting it as changed with a `git status`, but I can't seem to add with the globbing pattern.

I'm not asking HOW to recursively add files by pattern, git, (or bash?) already does that, as explained in my first example.

System:

- OSX 10.10.5
- GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
- git version 2.3.8 (Apple Git-58)

Comment: does `ls *.xml` (or  `dir *.xml`) show all the files?  Just verifying that there are no trailing chars(like  space, or something un printable).

Comment: yes, that works as expected

Comment: Is the xml file you are trying to add at the root of your repository, or a few directory levels down?

Comment: it could possibly be in a global ignore file

Comment: `git add -f *.xml` what happens?

Comment: They're nested, so there are some in the root, some in subfolders and so on. There's such a thing as a global ignore file?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr nothing changes when using the -f flag

Comment: yes, `[core] excludesfile = ~/.gitignore` in your .gitconfig is an example of specifying a global ignore file. also, check that repo's `.git/info/exclude` file

Comment: @ColonelPanic i wonder if `-f` should do the job if the files are just ignored, no?

Comment: @ColonelPanic nothing in both places

Comment: Re: the zsh answer on the possible duplicate, could this be a shell thing? I'm running a normal Bash shell, but with nothing special in terms of globs

Comment: @JohnBupit IMHO I don't think it's a duplicate, but it's very similar

Comment: @BrDaHa As a first step, I would try adding one of those xml files explicitly by path instead of globbing in order to rule out any other weird problems

Comment: @ColonelPanic I can do that successfully. I know there are workarounds, but I wanted to know why this was happening

Comment: @BrDaHa the only other thing I can suggest is to start fresh and slowly add things back in until you find the problem. get rid of your shell init file and git config (just use a minimal necessary settings) then see what happens

Comment: ok. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote the glob so that it passed to `git` for processing, rather than expanded by the shell.

```
git add '*.xml'
```

Comment: Ah, I thought it had something to do with shell expansion. Thanks! But do you know why it would work (recursively, even) for *.java (without quotes)

Comment: @BrDaHa If there's no `.java` files in the current directory, the shell will pass `*.java` to `git add` just as if you'd written `git add '*.java'`. This assumes you don't have `nullglob` set, in which case `git-add` would get no arguments.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you @Schwern!

Answer (score 0):

> They're nested, so there are some in the root, some in subfolders and so on.

`git add *.xml` will only add XML files *in the current directory*. Shell globbing does not include subdirectories.  This is a general shell thing.

If you pass a literal glob to `git add` it will apply it recursively.

```
git add '*.xml'
```

This is a feature of `git-add`. If you want something like this in general you can [turn on recursive globbing in bash 4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/recursive-glob).

```
git add **/*.xml
```

Or you can use `find` and `xargs`.

```
find . -name '*.xml' | xargs git add
```

Comment: You don't have to specify the pattern twice with `globstar`: `git add **/*.xml` is enough…

Comment: `find` contains loop within itself: `find . -name '*.xml' -exec git add {} \+`

Comment: And also, please don't use `xargs` like this… `find` has `-exec` to avoid (broken) trickeries like this: `find . -name '*.xml' -exec git add {} +`. By the way, the two are subtly different: `find` will find hidden files, but shell glob won't, _unless `shopt -s dotglob` is set._ Also, with `find` you can (and maybe should) specify `-type f`; with shell globs, you can't avoid directories from being globbed.

Comment: An actually, thinking about it: `find` is going to recurse in the `.git/` folder (unless you tell him not to, which becomes trickier)… the best option, really, is to let `git `deal with it with `git add '*.xml'`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You're right, I was using an older version of bash. As for `find` going into the `.git` directory, you're right, but it's mostly harmless.