Git (v 2.20) is no adding text files others do
I am using git version
git version 2.20.0.windows.1

I have problem with adding *.txt files.
I have created a project. There was only PCB files. At the beginning.
I have commited it.
Then I have generated project with STM CubeMX.
I started adding files with
git add *.c 

command.
After sometime I see with
git status -u 

that there are a lot of *.txt files.
I add them with
git add *.txt 

command.
There is nothing in respond but when I do
git status -u 

there are still *.txt files marked as Untracked.
The path to the typical txt file looks like that:
D:\projects\srm\srm_frmw_v10\keil\Drivers\CMSIS\LICENSE.txt

That file is not added.
But the weird thing that if i add txt file to this level
D:\projects\srm\test.txt

it is added with no problem.
But if I add txt file one level deeper
D:\projects\srm\srm_frmw_v10\test.txt

it can't be added.
But I can add directly specifying the path
git add D:\projects\srm\srm_frmw_v10\test.txt

file is added.
But I I put a test file like this in
D:\projects\srm\srm_frmw_v10\test.jjj

and call
git add *.jjj 

it adds this file.
What the hell is going on!!
Maybe my Gitis outdated and there is a bug in it?
Or maybe there are some diagnostic command to run?
Thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32875248/7976758 git add "*.txt" https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+add+txt+recursive

Right, what phd wrote. *.txt doesn't ever reach git, because it is expanded by your shell before the git process is even started

Yes. This is exactly what is happening. I will find out later what the hell is shell doing and not passing my parameters directly to git. Please don't explain that. I want to find  that by myself. :)

@zulunation Start with comparing echo *.txt and echo "*.txt" ;  dir *.txt and dir "*.txt"
